# Not connecting form data to db correctly in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which takes in 3 values: `taste`, `name` and `description` of a dessert.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $cake = Desserts::create([
        'taste' => $request->input('Taste'),
        'name' => .. (same)
        'description' => ..
    ])->id; 
}
```

In `$request->input('Taste')`, the 'Taste' refers to the **NAME** given to the entry field which the user uses to enter the taste details of the dessert. However, this syntax doesn't work (i.e. not updating to the db) and even though I do have values entered in the actual form, the error is that I get the following integrity constraint violation:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'taste' cannot be null
```

I don't quite understand why it is classified as null when I've clearly entered values in the entry field.

Also, the reason why I have `->id` because I want to use the `$cake` variable through the ID associated with this dessert for something else so it has to be in this format

Form example:

```
<v-text-field
v-model="thedessertitems"
>
</v-text-field>
```

Inside data:

```
thedessertitems: [
    {id:10, name:'Taste'}, 
    {id:11, name:'Name'},
    {id:12, name:'Description'}
]
```

Comment: use `dd($request->all())` and see what it is.

Comment: Can you please show your form?, `$request->input('Taste')` is correct, are you certain the form field correctly has a `name='Taste'` property?

Comment: I'm using Vuetify so v-model is linked to an array thedessertitems: [{id: 10, name: 'Taste'}] through which the name is specified. The form is a v-text-field (edited my question to include form)

Comment: The `thedessertitems` is defined as an array, so what are you trying to do with  `v-model="thedessertitems"`?. This is a vue issue, nothing to do with laravel

Answer (score 0):

first check $request->input('Taste') is correctly coming to method .(by using `dd($request->input('Taste'))` or `die(json_encode($request->input('Taste'));`   )

then go into 'Desserts' model and check '`protected $fillable = ['taste'];`' is exist..
you are doing mass assignment and mass assignment need to set $fillable. thank you.